# I need a voice interpreter and translator for an app... where do I go?

Tags: voice-recognition, language-translation

Does anyone know where I can find a voice interpreter and translator that I can use on an app? I want voice recognition on a few languages that get translated in to text. Where can I find this or where should I start? I am a rookie so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a commercial solution? If so, Dragon has SDKs

http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/products/sdk/developers.asp

Comment: Yea I am looking to have it implemented in to an app and sold.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, but they do not support the languages I need. I need Japanese and Vietnamese.